# Assigning char to char* using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Let's say I have a char *str and I want to assign it characters one by time using using pointers and incrementing ?

I've done :

```
char *str;
char c = 'a';
*str++ = c;
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do what? Do you understand *why* it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work because `str` points to nothing determinate. There is no "there" there.

Comment: I like the structure of the *There is no "there" there.* sentence...

Comment: @Eugene Sh it can be extended char **str;  no there there there

Comment: _one by time using using pointers and incrementing_? I have no clue what you're even asking.

Comment: "using using pointers" is probably referring a pointer to pointer :D

Comment: Are you trying to treat `str` as an array?  If so, you've failed to give it any space.

Comment: And what is the value of `str` (*i.e.*, what does it point to)? (HINT: you never assigned it.)

Comment: I understood why it doesn't work. I just want to assign chars one by time to a char array. The steps will be : assign a char to the string at the first address, then increment the address and assign a new char to that incremented address. str was previously initialized with malloc.

Comment: The question you posted is quite vague: *But it doesn't work. How can I do that?*. Assigning an appropriate value to `str` is how it's done. The rest of your code looks basically OK other than keeping track of how many characters you assign versus how much space `str` might point to. You can use `malloc` (`str = malloc(...);`), for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str` is just a pointer. It doesn't point anywhere valid (especially not to some memory you could write to). A simple possibility would be to have it point to an array:

```
char buf[1024] = {0}; // room for 1024 chars (or 1023 + a 0 byte for a string)
char *str = buf;
char c = 'a';
*str++ = c;
```

Answer (score 3):

`char *str` is a pointer to a char (or an array of chars), however, you never assigned it. As has been mentioned earlier a `char *` basically says "go there" but there is no there there, you never gave it a value. You first need to use `malloc` to create space to put things in. Here's an example

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10) //allocate space for 10 chars
char c = 'a';
str[0] = c;
```

no error check was made to malloc which you should do in your own program. You can also do it as such

```
char str[10];
char c = 'a';
str[0] = c;
```

however with this method you will be restricted to 10 chars and you cannot change that amount, with the previous method you can use `realloc` to get more or less space in your array.

Answer (score 1):

> > But it doesn't work.

```
char* str;
```

... is not initialized to anything, therefore dereferencing it is to undefined behaviour. If it where initialized, then in expression `*str++ = c;` str++ is a post-increment operator, which returns a copy of the pointer whilst incrementing the original. The effect is that the copy points to the previous, and therefore what is pointed to by the previous pointer is assigned c.

To which part that doesn't work are you referring?

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in one of the comments, a copy is not really returned but the value is increment in place after having been evaluated.

Comment: It doesn't "return a copy". The `++` operator modifies the object  (in this case the pointer) in place. It *evaluates* to the value *before* incrementing.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, in the case of builtin types this is true, yes, but I like to conceptualize is by explaining it as for non-builtins

Comment: This is C. There are no (user-)overloaded operators.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I realize this (that operator overloading only applies to c++), and that this is a "C" group. I still think that conceptually, thinking of a copy of the previous being returned whilst the original is incremented is helpful, irrespective of language (c/c++). Also, if there is an evaluation prior to the increment, the assigment makes a copy, not? Therefore:

char* p2 = p1++; //assignment to lvalue... returns a copy

Comment: @FelixPalmen, also char c = *p++; ... to me effectively implies, the lvalue of what is returned by p++, dereferenced. Yes, the original may be evaluated, but the "copy" is returned, as it amounts to an lvalue

Comment: the right hand side is just an expression, this expression has a value. Only the *assignment* is taking a copy. I prefer to stick to how it works according to the C standard. Otherwise, you'd say for `int b = a;` that `a` "returns a copy of a" ... You may think this is nitpicking (it is to some extent); I find it useful to use the correct terms. Expressions don't "return" anything, functions do.

Answer (score 1):

As a variable with automatic storage duration the pointer `str` has indeterminate value. If even it had the static storage duration its value would be NULL. So you may not use such a pointer to store data.

What you mean can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[11];

    char *p = s;

    while (p != s + sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ) - 1 ) *p++ = 'a';
    *p = '\0';

    puts(s);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Here in the program the pointer `p` of the type `char *` is initialized by the address of the first character of the array `s`.

Thus this statement used in the loop

```
*p++ = 'a';
```

fills sequentially the array with the character `'a'`.

The next example is more interesting

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * copy_string(char *dsn, const char *src)
{
    for (char *p = dsn; (*p++ = *src++) != '\0'; )
    {
        //  empty body
    }

    return dsn;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *src = "Hi QBl";
    char dsn[7];

    puts(copy_string(dsn, src));

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hi QBl
```

Here is a demonstration of a function that copies one character array containing a string into another character array using pointers.